# ionic io init command output ERROR] Unable to find command: io init [Ionic Auth Service]

Tags: ionic-framework

i just started learning ionic yesterday, and i have stumbled problem upon the creation of Auth service,

i refer on the step to create Auth service from here

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/get-started-with-ionic-services-auth--cms-28705

`npm --version` installed is 6.7.0

`ionic --version` installed is 5.2.6

so i start by first

`ionic start authApp blank`

then cd to the project directory

`npm install @ionic/cloud-angular --save`

then upon writing below command

`ionic io init`

error as below appear

ERROR] Unable to find command: io init

i have tried restarting terminal that i use which is Laragon Terminal

- i am web developer transfering to mobile development, and using Laragon as web IDE, so as Laragon already included with npm i continued to develop mobile application using Laragon IDE

i also close any apps that might interfere with the application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See community moderator Messege

The command “`ionic io`” was removed in `CLI v3`

> https://forum.ionicframework.com/u/Sujan12
>
> https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-io-init-error-unable-to-find-command/89680

Comment: if ionic io is removed what is the proper command line operator i can refer to input for installation of Auth services

Comment: do you want to genarate service?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the command `ionic login`.

Comment: Hi SalsaDev, thank you for your contribution. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. Please elaborate on the solution and provide context so others can learn why your answer solves the problem.